# WebView app to just load in a webpage. Hard to get approval by Apple?

Tags: ios, webview, appstore-approval, rules

I'm an educator and wish to build an app for my students. It will be quite basic with a login so they can find their info, invoices, ... But it would be really handy for them to have an app for this instead of using the webbrowser.

But it wouldn't be financially interesting to build an native app from scratch and since this functionality already exists op web. So I would like to use WebView instead to load this part of my website and won't have to maintain the app.

I heard Apple can give you hard time and decline your app if it only uses Webview to load a webpage. Is that correct?

Comment: [Perhaps.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/fnord)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your site is responsive and within the webview it presents application appearance it becomes easier to be approved. If they refuse you can put a single native functionality to justify being an app, or try to cache the site on the local disk.

You said you have a login system for your students, and it is important to register on the site as well.